# Can we Change boolean value in while's conditinon

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

there are default code of while loop
like.

```
while(true)
{
    //Default value in side "While(true/false){}"
}
```

we are define `true` inside while loop condition for make infinite loop.
is there any way to change that boolean value from that while loop block without make an boolean object.

Comment: No, thats not possible.

Comment: any reasion...?

Comment: You can use `break` or, if your while-loop is isolated to a method, `return` to end the loop without declaring a flag.

Comment: That's not how Java is designed

Comment: Because it is value, not variable.

Comment: You should read some tutorials, documentation and specification before asking such questions.

Comment: so...only allowed to define boolean value directly...?

Comment: Anyway your question may be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Is your goal stopping the loop or changing true to false?

Comment: @mak `boolean x = true; while(x) { x = false; }` - can you please explain why you cannot do just that?

Comment: yes i can do that...but can we change boolean value,which is define in directly

Comment: sorry @pshemo  i don't know XY problem but my goal is that ,you are right

Comment: Sorry, but for question "is your goal [A] or [B]?" answer: "yes it is" doesn't make things clearer... Anyway if your goal is to exit from loop then aside from making loop condition to `false` you can use `break;` instruction inside loop. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: @pshemo yes my goal is changing true of false without create var.

Comment: thanks for continue that discuss i hope you understand my problem, i know some trick that can change value in `while` condition like make an `boolean` object or break condition. but i want to change value in while loop which is defined directly,but i don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

`true` isn't a variable! It is a **literal**, a boolean value. You can't change values after the fact.

If you want to dynamically control your loop, you need something like:

```
boolean keepGoing = true;
while (keepGoing) {
  ...
  if (someThing) {
    keepGoing = false;
  }
}
```